# relationship between the $2$-norm of a symmetric matrix and its maximum eigenvalue.

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have an $N\times N$ symmetric matrix $Q$, what is the relationship between $\|Q\|$ and its maximum eigenvalue, where $\|\|$ is the $2$nd norm?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius

Answer (score 0):

The general answer to this is this $\|Q\| = \max \{|\lambda_{\max}(Q)|, |\lambda_{\min}(Q)|\}$. To see why this is true, consider $Q = I_{N}$ for the first case and $Q = -I_{N}$ for the second case.

Comment: Those example don't really do anything to show *why* the result should hold.  They are examples, though.

Comment: It would be far clearer to write this as the maximum absolute value of the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Q=UDU^\top$ be the eigendecomposition of $Q$ with $U$ orthogonal and $D = \text{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ where $\lambda_1 \ge \cdots \ge \lambda_n$.

$$\max_{v : \|v\|_2=1} \|Qv\|_2 = \max_{v : \|v\|_2=1} \sqrt{v^\top Q^\top Q v} = \max_{u : \|u\|_2=1} \sqrt{u^\top D^2 u} = \max_{u : \|u\|_2=1} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n  \lambda_i^2 u_i^2}$$

By Hölder's inequality and the constraint $\|u\|_2=1$, we have $$\max_{u : \|u_2\|_2=1} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n  \lambda_i^2 u_i^2} \le \sqrt{\max_i \lambda_i^2} = \max_i |\lambda_i|.$$
Equality is attained by taking $u=e_1$.